# Javascript Function Throttling

Tags: javascript, throttling

I want to use a JS Throttle. But i'm struggeling to get it work correctly.

I tried the code from this article:
https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

But the Throttle does not work as intended, since everytime i click on the button, one "|" is added to the div. No clicks were discarded.

where is the misstake?

```js
function foo() {
 $("#respond").append("|");
}

const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle
  return function() {
    const args = arguments
    const context = this
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func.apply(context, args)
      inThrottle = true
      setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
    }
  }
}

var onClick = function() {
    throttle(foo(), 50000);
};

$('#button').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
<div id="respond"></div>
```

Comment: `foo()` -> `foo` otherwise you are executing the function *immediately* instead of giving an function reference to execute later.

Comment: You also seem to be returning a function from `throttle` but you never execute it. Looking at the code, it seems you actually want to do `$('#button').click(throttle(foo, 50000));` so you make the returned function the handler.

Comment: Ah thank you! 
But why does this:   `$('#button').click(throttle(foo, 50000));` work, but `"var onClick = function() {
    throttle(foo, 50000);
};

$('#button').click(onClick);"` this not?

Comment: Because `throttle(foo, 50000)` still returns a function reference that you need to execute later. Essentially what what happens is that your handler does `var functionReference =  throttle(foo, 50000)` and then does nothing, instead of calling `functionReference()`. Having a function that simply calls another function with no arguments (remember that the function you get doesn't take any, so you sort of get is a bit of a code smell `giveCallback(() => otherFunc())` is easier expressed as `giveCallback(otherFunc)`, hence why I suggested directly giving this `functionReference` as the handler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for `throttle(func, limit)` to work, there can only be one instance of its product.

The problem is that the `onClick` function in your example creates a new instance each time it is called.

This makes the underlying `inThrottle` variable meaningless, as a new copy is created for each click.

The solution is to call one single instance the product of `throttle(foo, 50000)` directly.

Also, `foo` itself should be passed (not its product).

See below for a practical example, as well as [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) for more info.

```js
// Foo.
const foo = (...args) => {
  $("#respond").append("|");
}

// Throttle.
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
  let inThrottle
  return (...args) => {
    if (!inThrottle) {
      func(...args)
      inThrottle = setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
    }
  }
}

// On Click.
const onClick = throttle(foo, 1000)

// Button - Click.
$('#button').click(onClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
<div id="respond"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is old.

I made a small snippet. I think it should qualify as a simple way to throttle a function. This will guarantee a call every wait milliseconds.

```js
function throttle( fn, wait ){
  let lastCall = 0;
    return function(){
    if( Date.now() - lastCall > wait  ){
      lastCall = Date.now()
      fn()
    }
  }
}

var counter = 0

var count = () => document.querySelector("#count").textContent = ++counter

window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle( count, 1000 ) )
```

```css
body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='count'>
  0
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your onClick is creating a new throttled function on every invoke.  You have to ensure that is only throttled once

```
var onClick = function() {
    throttle(foo(), 50000);
};
// TO

var onClick = throttle(foo, 50000);
```