# Javascript block multiple executions

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm currently writing a Python application using a web framework. I implemented a form who call javascript function, who call Python WebService. Those webservices are pretty heavy so I want to implement a security to avoid running the javascript multiple times and wait to the WS response before allow another call.

Here is a piece of HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input onfocusout="ocr_on_fly(false, this)" onfocusin="ocr_on_fly(true, this)" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
</div>
```

The call of WS in JS in the `ocr_on_fly` function :

```
onSelectEnd: function(img, selection){
    if(selection['width'] !== 0 && selection['height'] !== 0){
        $.post({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/pdf/ocr",
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify({
                selection   : selection,
                fileName    : $('#my-image')[0].src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''),
                thumbSize   : {width: img.width, height:img.height}
            })
        }

        }).then(function(data) {
                input.value = data['result'];
        });
    }
}
```

I heard about setTimeout, but not sure it's the better things because I didn't want to block the execution of the script for a specified time. The script could take 0.1s as it could take 10s or more

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that should be done in python, webservice-side. Javascript should only receive a `Please wait for a previous process to end` message.

Comment: What do you prefer to happen - if the call is executed, say, three times in a short span, should you get the first result or the last only?

Comment: you can easily set a global variable, when you call the script you set it to true and when response to false, , if the value is true then the webservice doesnt execute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Function Throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867999/javascript-function-throttling)

Comment: There are any number of ways to throttle requests from the client side, including libraries that handle this for you, or simple checking to see if a request is in flight.

Comment: Thanks all for your answer :) 
@axelaxel I used the global var and it works pretty well with an easy implementation. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RandyCasburn not really because I don't wan't to block the launch of my script using a timer, it do not solve my problem. But thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a global variable then when you call your script set it to `true`.

Then when the response is completed you set it to `false`.

Check this variable before making the request; if it's already been set to `true`, don't make the request.