# How can I tell my javascript to wait until the server is done?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

In my  web app, I have a page where users can copy books from their library.

On the website, when a user clicks the `copy` button, the app executes this bit of Backbone.js code:

```
clonebook: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.book.clone().then((r) => {
        self.model.collection.add(r);
    });
},
```

In My SQL Server database, `book` looks like this:

> bookId, bookTitle, authorId, libraryId, rowOrderNumber

The problem is, if the user tries to clone multiple books really fast by hitting the `copy` button, the `rowOrderNumber` can get out of whack.

Is there a way to tell the Backbone clone method to wait until the database or server has completed a clone process before going on to the next one?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867999/javascript-function-throttling

Comment: @Konrad can you please explain to me which part of that answer would help my question?  thanks!

Comment: Does `self.model.collection.add(r)` return promise as well?

Comment: @Konrad I believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use backbone, but

```
clonebook: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.loading = true
    this.book.clone().then((r) => {
        self.model.collection.add(r).then(() => {
          self.loading = false
        });
    });
},
```

Not you have to use this `loading` somehow to disable the button

Answer (score 2):

The most common UX pattern for this is to disable the button when the process starts, and enable when finished.

```
clonebook: function () {
    var self = this;
    // disable clone button
    this.book.clone().then((r) => {
        self.model.collection.add(r);
        // enable clone button
    });
},
```

Comment: Do you mean I should set a timeout or something in javascript?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Edit added